# Environment or command to handle multiple situations with the lettrine package

Tags: macros, environments, memoir, lettrine

I wrote my own command to put the first letter bigger.

But then I discovered the lettrine package which does more interesting things. Now I would like to have an environment or a command from which to handle various situations:

1. Normal cases
2. Cases with only one letter (disastrous exit)
3. Cases with previous content (for example a number)
4. Cases with quotes, and if possible combining the content with \ textquote from the csquotes package

This is my EMV:

```
\documentclass[ebook,10pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{lettrine}  
\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{{\color{red}\hrulefill}\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}{\color{red}\hrulefill}}}}
\renewcommand\subsubsecheadstyle{\Large\noindent\ruleline}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{red}}

\newenvironment{body}{%
    \addvspace{\topsep}% Space above
}{%
    \unskip\par
    \addvspace{\topsep}% Space below
    %\needspace{15\baselineskip}
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{body}    
    \lettrine[findent=.3em]{A}{l} \lipsum[1] %1. normal case
    \end{body}  

    \begin{body}
    \lettrine[findent=.3em]{Y} \lipsum[2]] %2. case unique character (disaster)
    \end{body}  

    \begin{body}
    \lettrine[findent=.3em, ante={1. }]{C}{on} \lipsum[3] %3. case  with "ante" content (number)
                                                            
    \end{body}  
        
    \begin{body}
    \lettrine[findent=.3em, ante={"}]{Q}{uoted"} \lipsum[4] %4. case    with "ante" (quote)
                                                            %   who to combine with txtquote{} of csquotes package
    
\end{body}
            
\end{document}
```

This is the ouput:

[image]

How could I automate my use of lettrine, to make calls more or less like this:

1. `\mylt {A}{l} more text`
2. `\mylt {Y} more text and correction of the disaster on this case`
3. `\mylt {1. }{C}{on} more text (here 1. is the content for "ante"`
4. `\mylt ****No idee how to manage the quotes and combine with csquotes`

Comment: You can't (ordinarily) have commands with a variable number of _mandatory_ options.

Comment: @DG' I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I just want to make it easier to write in my documents, so I don't have to write `\lettrine[findent=.3em]{A}{l}` OR `\lettrine[findent=.3em]{Y}` OR `\lettrine[findent=.3em, ante={1. }]{C}{on}` OR `\lettrine[findent=.3em, ante={"}]{Q}{uoted"}` ... I am looking to simplify the writing to something that is short and easily remembered, as I explain in the examples at the end.

Comment: Btw. `\lettrine[findent=.3em]{Y}` takes whatever comes after as the second mandatory argument. If you really want only one letter, use `\lettrine[findent=.3em]{Y}{}`

Comment: @DG' It's OK for the disaster at point (2). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to do it with the following command:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ltr{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{\lettrine[findent=.3em, ante={#1}]{#2}}
\def\@without#1{\lettrine[findent=.3em]{#1}}
\makeatother
```

In this way I can simplify my use of lettrine, writing the following in the source code, according to the different cases exposed:

```
\ltr {A}{b}

\ltr [For ant=] {A}{b}

 ... etc
```

In the case of `textquote{}`, since it seemed complicated to my limited knowledge, I have chosen to put the type of opening and closing quotation mark directly in the text.

One example with the solution:

```
\documentclass[ebook,8pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{lettrine}  
\usepackage{csquotes} 

\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{1.5cm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{4cm}{1.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{red}}

\newenvironment{body}{%
    \addvspace{\topsep}% Space above
}{%
    \unskip\par
    \addvspace{\topsep}% Space below
    %\needspace{15\baselineskip}
}

\makeatletter
\def\ltr{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}
\def\@with[#1]#2{\lettrine[findent=.3em, ante={#1}]{#2}}
\def\@without#1{\lettrine[findent=.3em]{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{body}        

\ltr{A}{l} \lipsum[1]                 %1. normal case

\ltr{Y}{} \lipsum[2]                  %2. case unique character (thanks @DG')

\ltr[1. ]{C}{on} \lipsum[3]           %3. case with "ante"

\ltr[«]{Q}{uoted»} \lipsum[4]         %4. case with quotes, the same solution for case 3

\end{body}
            
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]